# Linking MS Access and database server without installing any additional drivers

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, ms-access, odbc

on our company-website, we have an `html`-form, where an e-mail is generated via `php` for consulting reasons - which works fine. My superiors want me to save the information of the `html`-form into an `MS Access`-database.

I couldn't come up with a solution that directly writes from `php` into `MS Access` - so I convinced them to go with `MySQL` via `phpMyAdmin` - linking the tables via `ODBC` in `Access`.

The connection between `php` and `MySQL` was easy, and the connection between `MS Access` and `MySQL` would've also been:

To do that, an `ODBC-MySQL-Provider` is required for each Client to open the Database, which the IT-department doesn't want to install.

We also use an `MS SQL Server` on an `Windows Server` - I could also connect php to `SQL Server` -  but in this case we need to install the `ODBC SQL Server Provider` when linking the tables or the `SQL Server Native Clients` if we go with `Ado`. - IT guys:

> no installation of providers on all clients.

My question is:

> Is there any possible solution for accessing `MySQL/SQL Server`
>   from `MS Access` without the installation of `ODBC-Providers` at all?

I have really high pressure on this and can't find anything that could satisfy user-needs and expectations.

Thanks in advance

Baris

Edit: the working `php/MySQL`-Code - based on `mysqli`

```
$servername = "----------.de";
$username = "-------";
$password = "--------";
$dbName = "---------";
$port = "-------";

$con= mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbName, $port );
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

The following connection-string works for connecting to a server-side `ms sqlserver` from `MS Access` with the integrated `SQLSRV32.dll`-provider. Thanks to GordThompson

```
cs = "Driver={SQL Server};"
cs = cs & "Server=ip-adress,port-number;"
cs = cs & "Database=database-name;"
con.Open cs, "username", "password"
```

Since there is a possiblity to connect to the `SQL Server` without additional provider, I am going for the `PDO/SQLServer`-combination, and loading the data based on the connection-string above.

Comment: why on earth are you doing this? use PDO and write directly in to the sql server no need for messing around with access or mysql since you have a full blown sql server sat there already or even better... web site php, mysql, internal website php they can access the data via a web browser or just email it to them if they're that retarded

Comment: I have no other choice than go with MS Access as the front-end database. The requirements are pretty clear, the data needs to find its way to MS Access in the end. I am not happy about that either, but the key stakeholders really want to stick with MS Access and the problem with SQL Server and the ODBC providers remain

Comment: You need to install some kind of a driver on each client running the ms access front-end database to connect to mysql or ms sql. If IT refuses to install quite known and well tested drivers on all clients, then what is the chance that they are willing to install some other driver's? Btw, ms access install the native sql server driver under default settings because of ms access projects type databases, where the backend is in ms sql, but the fronend is in ms access. So, I would check if ms sql driver is not installed already.

Comment: Additionally, if the key stakeholders insist on retaining the ms access front-end, then they should instruct IT to have the necessary drivers installed on all clients.

Comment: @Shadow Some time ago I built connection strings for SQL Server in VBA -  the SQLNCLI wasn't installed and I had to install it manually for few developers.
The key stakeholders say that the IT department want us to stay in the standard configuration and that's it. I don't want to go much into politics, but it's a joke.

Comment: You may want to consider the following setup then: a) Split your ms access database into 2 databases, 1 for front end installed on all clients, and 1 for backend, where all data resides (this is installed on a server computer). b) link the tables in the backend database to the frontend databases c) install myodbc or ms sql driver on the server computer only where the backend database resides. d) sync your data with the backend database only.

Comment: What about the older "SQL Server" ODBC driver (SQLSRV32.DLL) that is installed as a standard component of Windows itself? Has your company taken that away from you as well?

Comment: Your PHP/MySQL code doesn't really help much. You've already told us that getting the data from PHP into MySQL is not the problem. (And you still haven't answered my question about the "SQL Server" driver.)

Comment: @GordThompson , the code was intended for the user Parfait. Where can I look if the SQLSRV32.dll is available? I am at the company again on friday. In `VBA`, the connection String:`Driver={SQL Server};Server=IP-address,Port;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;` would work between MS Access and SQL Server (via SQLSRV32.dll) without the installation of any additional drivers ?

Comment: The "SQL Server" driver is included as part of a normal Windows install so that connection string *should* work without any additional components having to be installed. (Assuming that the network configuration allows the connection between the two machines.)

Comment: @GordThompson, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the overriding concern is to avoid installing additional drivers on the client machines and you have a Microsoft SQL Server available to you then you can

1. Have your PHP script write the required information to the SQL Server, and then
2. Create an Access process that retrieves the information from the SQL Server using the "SQL Server" ODBC driver that is installed with every copy of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, PHP can absolutely connect to an MS Access database (specifically the Jet/ACE SQL Engine). In modern day computing, practically all general purpose languages (C#, Java, PHP, Perl, Python, R, VB) can connect to all popular relational database management systems (RDMS) -both file level (SQLite, MS Access) and server level (SQL Server, MySQL, Postgre, Oracle, DB2), each using some type of customized or generalized library.

With PHP's [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php), you can practically interchange the connected backend database. So however you connect to MySQL, you can model such a connection with other databases. The web popularity of PHP/MySQL make it seem they are married to each other but they are not! Below are examples using DSN, Driver, and even PHP's own API, [sqlsrv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php).

**MS ACCESS**

```
# USING DSN
$database="C:\Path\To\Database\File.accdb";
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:DSN=MS Access Database;DBq=$database;");
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";    
    $STH = $dbh->query($sql);    
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit;
}
# close the connection
$dbh = null;


# USING DRIVER (NON-DSN)
$database="C:\Path\To\Database\File.accdb";
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBq=$database;");    
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";    
    $STH = $dbh->query($sql);    
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit;
}
# close the connection
$dbh = null;
```

**SQL SERVER**

```
# WITH ODBC DRIVER PDO
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;database=$database",$username,$password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tablename";    
    $STH = $dbh->query($sql);    
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit;
}
# close the connection
$dbh = null;

# WITH SQLSRV PDO
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;database=$database",$username,$password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.tablename";    
    $STH = $dbh->query($sql);    
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit;
}
# close the connection
$dbh = null;
```

Extra resource for other language connections:

https://github.com/ParfaitG/DATABASE_CONNECTIONS

Comment: The problem I see is how the connection-string is build, namely there is only a 

`$database="C:\Path\To\Database\File.accdb";` -> No IP, no port as in server-side DBMS (SQL Server, MySQL).

The `CMS` and the client-computers with `MS Access` are not in the same environment, so that I assume we must give `PDO` some kind of address (IP) or something like that.

Don't I have to tell `PDO` at least where to find the file-path to the client-computers?

Comment: MS Access, a file level DB, does not operate remotely with IP but on a LAN network. In PHP you can use the current directory value: ` $cd = dirname(__FILE__); $database=$cd.'/File.accdb';` and save database relative to script. As shown, PDO for MS Access uses the installed Access Driver (same with VBA's ADO).

Comment: I should add, since the Jet/ACE database are .DLL files, MS Access only runs on Windows environments. Sorry if this all confusing but if we go back to your central need of saving HTML form into Access, PHP running on a PC server not Linux/Unix, wth database residing on server, PHP can parse html and insert data into Access db. Please update your post with working PHP/MySQL code so I can show you specifically.

Comment: with `php/on server` & `ms access/on client-pc` this is not possible, right?

Comment: Again, MS Access does not connect remotely. If Access file resided on Windows web server with PHP, then a PHP/MS Access script like above can work. Alternatively, have PHP save form data in HTML/XML/txt/csv format, then email or transfer file to FTP where Access VBA (or other language) can download and import locally. Quite a bit of infrastructure to integrate an enterprise RDMS, SQL Server, just for an HTML data task.